# Click to select row in gridview causing postback in edit mode

Tags: asp.net, select, gridview, onclick, edit

Currently, when a user clicks on anywhere on a row, it selects that row. Unfortunately, when in edit mode (after clicking on "edit'), the form does a postback every time a user clicks anywhere on the form. How do I disable this and let the user edit the row in peace?

This is what I have that enables click to select row:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            List<int> notClickable = new List<int>();
            {
                notClickable.Add(0);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (!notClickable.Contains(i))
                {
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                    e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                }
            }

            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle");
            e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
            e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
        }
    }
```

Revised code that solves the problem:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCreated(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            if (GridView1.EditIndex != -1)
            {
                e.Row.Attributes.Remove("onmouseover");
            }
            else
            {
                List<int> notClickable = new List<int>();
                {
                    notClickable.Add(0);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!notClickable.Contains(i))
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                        e.Row.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] = this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
                    }
                }

                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.originalstyle=this.style.backgroundColor;this.style.backgroundColor='#ceedfc'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.style.backgroundColor=this.originalstyle");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("style", "cursor:pointer;");
                e.Row.ToolTip = "Click to select row";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I know this is old - but just wanted to say thanks for the revised code/answer! I didn't realize how simple it would be to solve my problem (very similar to yours) until I saw this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your select function, have it remove the onclick attributes. Then when you are done editing, add it back.

Comment: Thanks, Lawrence. I did something similar to your suggestion. See edit.